# Vega-Lite Clock (Using a Timer in Vega-Lite)

Tags: json, visualization, vega-lite

I am developing a clock with vega-lite and want to know if it is possible to auto refresh the chart every second. I am currently doing it with vegaEmbed, however, that would not work well with clients using Deneb etc.

Thanks

```
vegaEmbed('#vis', generateSpec())
.then((result) => {
view = result.view;
})
.catch(console.error);

setInterval(() => {
const newSpec = generateSpec();
vegaEmbed('#vis', newSpec, {actions: false}).then((result) => {
view = result.view;
}).catch(console.error);
}, 1000);
```

Comment: what do you mean by "improve"?

Comment: Just to make it more efficient and maybe to auto refresh without vega-embed would be good. Just wanted to share it with the community.

Comment: Looks good. You can use sequence expressions to generate your data instead of manually typing 1-12 and 1-60. See my waffle chart examples for how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to get a timer in Vega-Lite so you don't need vega-embed. You will get an underline in the editor but you can ignore it.

```
{
  "name": "time", 
     "on": [{"events": {"type": "timer", "throttle": 1000}, "update": "now()"}] 
},
```

This updates every second:

Full code of working clock in VL.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "description": "Vega-lite clock",
  "usermeta": {"embedOptions": {"renderer": "svg"}},
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"hour": "12", "min": "1", "minute": "01", "value": 1},
      {"hour": "12", "min": "2", "minute": "02", "value": 1},
      {"hour": "12", "min": "3", "minute": "03", "value": 1},
      {"hour": "12", "min": "4", "minute": "04", "value": 1},
      {"hour": "1", "min": "5", "minute": "05", "value": 1},
      {"hour": "1", "min": "6", "minute": "06", "value": 1},
      {"hour": "1", "min": "7", "minute": "07", "value": 1},
      {"hour": "1", "min": "8", "minute": "08", "value": 1},
      {"hour": "1", "min": "9", "minute": "09", "value": 1},
      {"hour": "2", "min": "10", "minute": "10", "value": 1},
      {"hour": "2", "min": "11", "minute": "11", "value": 1},
      {"hour": "2", "min": "12", "minute": "12", "value": 1},
      {"hour": "2", "min": "13", "minute": "13", "value": 1},
      {"hour": "2", "min": "14", "minute": "14", "value": 1},
      {"hour": "3", "min": "15", "minute": "15", "value": 1},
      {"hour": "3", "min": "16", "minute": "16", "value": 1},
      {"hour": "3", "min": "17", "minute": "17", "value": 1},
      {"hour": "3", "min": "18", "minute": "18", "value": 1},
      {"hour": "3", "min": "19", "minute": "19", "value": 1},
      {"hour": "4", "min": "20", "minute": "20", "value": 1},
      {"hour": "4", "min": "21", "minute": "21", "value": 1},
      {"hour": "4", "min": "22", "minute": "22", "value": 1},
      {"hour": "4", "min": "23", "minute": "23", "value": 1},
      {"hour": "4", "min": "24", "minute": "24", "value": 1},
      {"hour": "5", "min": "25", "minute": "25", "value": 1},
      {"hour": "5", "min": "26", "minute": "26", "value": 1},
      {"hour": "5", "min": "27", "minute": "27", "value": 1},
      {"hour": "5", "min": "28", "minute": "28", "value": 1},
      {"hour": "5", "min": "29", "minute": "29", "value": 1},
      {"hour": "6", "min": "30", "minute": "30", "value": 1},
      {"hour": "6", "min": "31", "minute": "31", "value": 1},
      {"hour": "6", "min": "32", "minute": "32", "value": 1},
      {"hour": "6", "min": "33", "minute": "33", "value": 1},
      {"hour": "6", "min": "34", "minute": "34", "value": 1},
      {"hour": "7", "min": "35", "minute": "35", "value": 1},
      {"hour": "7", "min": "36", "minute": "36", "value": 1},
      {"hour": "7", "min": "37", "minute": "37", "value": 1},
      {"hour": "7", "min": "38", "minute": "38", "value": 1},
      {"hour": "7", "min": "39", "minute": "39", "value": 1},
      {"hour": "8", "min": "40", "minute": "40", "value": 1},
      {"hour": "8", "min": "41", "minute": "41", "value": 1},
      {"hour": "8", "min": "42", "minute": "42", "value": 1},
      {"hour": "8", "min": "43", "minute": "43", "value": 1},
      {"hour": "8", "min": "44", "minute": "44", "value": 1},
      {"hour": "9", "min": "45", "minute": "45", "value": 1},
      {"hour": "9", "min": "46", "minute": "46", "value": 1},
      {"hour": "9", "min": "47", "minute": "47", "value": 1},
      {"hour": "9", "min": "48", "minute": "48", "value": 1},
      {"hour": "9", "min": "49", "minute": "49", "value": 1},
      {"hour": "10", "min": "50", "minute": "50", "value": 1},
      {"hour": "10", "min": "51", "minute": "51", "value": 1},
      {"hour": "10", "min": "52", "minute": "52", "value": 1},
      {"hour": "10", "min": "53", "minute": "53", "value": 1},
      {"hour": "10", "min": "54", "minute": "54", "value": 1},
      {"hour": "11", "min": "55", "minute": "55", "value": 1},
      {"hour": "11", "min": "56", "minute": "56", "value": 1},
      {"hour": "11", "min": "57", "minute": "57", "value": 1},
      {"hour": "11", "min": "58", "minute": "58", "value": 1},
      {"hour": "11", "min": "59", "minute": "59", "value": 1},
      {"hour": "12", "min": "0", "minute": "60", "value": 1}
    ]
  },
  "params": [
    {
      "name": "_svg_min",
      "value": "M -2 0 a 3 3 0 1 0 6 0 v -130 a 3 3 0 1 0 -6 0 z"
    },
    {
      "name": "_svg_hr",
      "value": "M -2 0 a 3 3 0 1 0 6 0 v -90 a 3 3 0 1 0 -6 0 z"
    },
    {"name": "_svg_second", "value": "M 0 -160 l 0 190"},
    {
      "name": "time",
      "on": [{"events": {"type": "timer", "throttle": 1000}, "update": "now()"}]
    }
  ],
  "transform": [
    {"joinaggregate": [{"op": "sum", "field": "value", "as": "total"}]},
    {
      "sort": [{"field": "minute"}],
      "window": [{"op": "sum", "field": "value", "as": "Cumulat"}],
      "frame": [null, 0]
    },
    {
      "calculate": "(360* ((datum.Cumulat) / datum.total))-90",
      "as": "percentage"
    },
    {"calculate": "minutes(time) / 60 * 360", "as": "min_degrees"},
    {
      "calculate": "((hours(time) % 12) * 30) + (minutes(time) / 60 * 30)",
      "as": "hr_degrees"
    },
    {"calculate": "seconds(time) * 6", "as": "sec_degrees"},
    {"calculate": "timeFormat(time, '%a %e')", "as": "curr_date1"},
    {"calculate": "timeFormat(time, '%B')", "as": "curr_date2"}
  ],
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": {"type": "arc", "outerRadius": 200, "innerRadius": 199},
      "encoding": {"color": {"value": "#dddddd"}}
    },
    {
      "mark": {
        "type": "text",
        "radius": 180,
        "fontSize": 50,
        "fontWeight": 400,
        "angle": {"expr": "datum.percentage"}
      },
      "encoding": {
        "theta": {"field": "Cumulat", "type": "quantitative"},
        "text": {"value": "-"},
        "color": {"value": "silver"}
      }
    },
    {
      "transform": [
        {
          "filter": {
            "field": "minute",
            "oneOf": [5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 60, 0]
          }
        }
      ],
      "mark": {
        "type": "text",
        "radius": 180,
        "fontSize": 50,
        "fontWeight": 400,
        "angle": {"expr": "datum.percentage"}
      },
      "encoding": {
        "theta": {"field": "Cumulat", "type": "quantitative"},
        "text": {"value": "-"},
        "color": {"value": "#1C1C1E"}
      }
    },
    {
      "transform": [{"filter": "datum.minute == minutes(time)"}],
      "mark": {
        "type": "text",
        "radius": 180,
        "fontSize": 50,
        "fontWeight": 400,
        "angle": {"expr": "datum.percentage"}
      },
      "encoding": {
        "theta": {"field": "Cumulat", "type": "quantitative"},
        "text": {"value": "-"},
        "color": {"value": "#F79100"}
      }
    },
    {
      "transform": [
        {
          "filter": "datum.minute == seconds(time) || seconds(time) == 0 && datum.minute == '60'"
        }
      ],
      "mark": {
        "type": "text",
        "radius": 180,
        "fontSize": 70,
        "fontWeight": 800,
        "angle": {"expr": "datum.percentage"}
      },
      "encoding": {
        "theta": {"field": "Cumulat", "type": "quantitative"},
        "text": {"value": "-"},
        "color": {"value": "#FFFFFF"}
      }
    },
    {
      "transform": [
        {
          "filter": "datum.minute == seconds(time) || seconds(time) == 0 && datum.minute == '60'"
        }
      ],
      "mark": {
        "type": "text",
        "radius": 190,
        "fontSize": 30,
        "fontWeight": 800,
        "angle": {"expr": "datum.percentage"}
      },
      "encoding": {
        "theta": {"field": "Cumulat", "type": "quantitative"},
        "text": {"value": ""},
        "color": {"value": "#F79100"}
      }
    },
    {
      "transform": [
        {
          "filter": {
            "field": "minute",
            "oneOf": [5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 60]
          }
        }
      ],
      "mark": {
        "type": "text",
        "radius": 145,
        "fontSize": 40,
        "fontWeight": 600,
        "font": "Arial"
      },
      "encoding": {
        "theta": {"field": "Cumulat", "type": "quantitative"},
        "text": {"field": "hour"},
        "color": {
          "condition": {
            "test": "datum.hour == hours(time) || datum.hour == hours(time)-12",
            "value": "#F79100"
          },
          "value": "black"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "transform": [
        {
          "filter": {
            "field": "minute",
            "oneOf": [5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 60, 0]
          }
        }
      ],
      "mark": {"type": "circle", "size": 500},
      "encoding": {"color": {"value": "#1C1C1E"}}
    },
    {
      "mark": {
        "type": "point",
        "size": 5.1,
        "shape": {"expr": "_svg_min"},
        "angle": {"expr": "datum.min_degrees"}
      },
      "encoding": {"fill": {"value": "#1C1C1E"}, "stroke": {"value": "#1C1C1E"}}
    },
    {
      "mark": {
        "type": "point",
        "size": 5.1,
        "shape": {"expr": "_svg_hr"},
        "angle": {"expr": "datum.hr_degrees"}
      },
      "encoding": {"fill": {"value": "#1C1C1E"}, "stroke": {"value": "#1C1C1E"}}
    },
    {
      "mark": {
        "type": "point",
        "size": 5.1,
        "shape": {"expr": "_svg_second"},
        "angle": {"expr": "datum.sec_degrees"}
      },
      "encoding": {"fill": {"value": "#F79100"}, "stroke": {"value": "#F79100"}}
    },
    {
      "mark": {"type": "circle", "size": 200},
      "encoding": {"color": {"value": "#F79100"}}
    },
    {
      "mark": {"type": "circle", "size": 50},
      "encoding": {"color": {"value": "#FFF"}}
    },
    {
      "transform": [{"filter": {"field": "minute", "oneOf": [14]}}],
      "mark": {
        "type": "text",
        "radius": 80,
        "fontSize": 18,
        "fontWeight": 600,
        "font": "Arial"
      },
      "encoding": {
        "theta": {"field": "Cumulat", "type": "quantitative"},
        "text": {"field": "curr_date1"},
        "color": {"value": "silver"}
      }
    },
    {
      "transform": [{"filter": {"field": "minute", "oneOf": [16]}}],
      "mark": {
        "type": "text",
        "radius": 80,
        "fontSize": 16,
        "fontWeight": 400,
        "font": "Arial"
      },
      "encoding": {
        "theta": {"field": "Cumulat", "type": "quantitative"},
        "text": {"field": "curr_date2"},
        "color": {"value": "silver"}
      }
    },
    {
      "transform": [{"filter": {"field": "minute", "oneOf": [60]}}],
      "mark": {
        "type": "text",
        "radius": 80,
        "fontSize": 28,
        "fontWeight": 400,
        "font": "Arial"
      },
      "encoding": {
        "theta": {"field": "Cumulat", "type": "quantitative"},
        "text": {"value": "VL"},
        "color": {"value": "#F79100"}
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks Davide! That's great. I updated my answer with some bug fixes also. The markers on outside of clock are now SVG too.

Answer (score 1):

Here are 2 updated versions based on Apple iOS styling.

There is one for both light and dark themes.

It now has smooth second hand scrolling and uses far less gpu/cpu.

**Light theme:**

[image]

```
{
"$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
"data": {"values": [{"value": 1}]},
"params": [
{
"name": "_svg_marker",
"value": "M -0.5 70 a 0.5 0.5 0 1 0 1 0 v -4 a 0.5 0.5 0 1 0 -1 0 z"
},
{
"name": "_svg_min",
"value": "M -2 0 a 2 2 0 1 0 4 0 v -130 a 2 2 0 1 0 -4 0 z"
},
{
"name": "_svg_min_big",
"value": "M -4 -25 a 4 4 0 1 0 8 0 v -120 a 4 4 0 1 0 -8 0 z"
},
{
"name": "_svg_hr",
"value": "M -2 0 a 2 2 0 1 0 4 0 v -90 a 2 2 0 1 0 -4 0 z"
},
{
"name": "_svg_hr_big",
"value": "M -4 -25 a 4 4 0 1 0 8 0 v -70 a 4 4 0 1 0 -8 0 z"
},
{"name": "_svg_sec", "value": "M 0 -170 l 0 190"},
{
"name": "time",
"on": [{"events": {"type": "timer", "throttle": 10}, "update": "now()"}]
}
],
"layer": [
{
"mark": {"type": "arc", "outerRadius": 200, "innerRadius": 199},
"encoding": {"fill": {"value": "silver"}}
},
{
"mark": {"type": "circle", "size": 500},
"encoding": {"color": {"value": "#515157"}, "opacity": {"value": 1}}
},
{
"transform": [
{"calculate": "sequence(0,5, 1)", "as": "pos"},
{"flatten": ["pos"]},
{"calculate": "timeFormat(time, '%A')", "as": "val"}
],
"mark": {
"type": "text",
"radius": 75,
"fontSize": 28,
"fontWeight": 400,
"font": "Arial"
},
"encoding": {
"theta": {"field": "pos"},
"text": {"value": "VL"},
"fill": {
"condition": [{"test": "datum.pos == 4", "value": "#F79100"}],
"value": "transparent"
}
}
},
{
"transform": [
{"calculate": "sequence(0,5, 1)", "as": "pos"},
{"flatten": ["pos"]},
{"calculate": "timeFormat(time, '%A')", "as": "val"}
],
"mark": {
"type": "text",
"radius": 75,
"fontSize": 18,
"fontWeight": 400,
"font": "Arial"
},
"encoding": {
"theta": {"field": "pos"},
"text": {"field": "val"},
"fill": {
"condition": [{"test": "datum.pos == 3", "value": "#B3B3B3"}],
"value": "transparent"
}
}
},
{
"transform": [
{"calculate": "sequence(0,5, 1)", "as": "pos"},
{"flatten": ["pos"]},
{"calculate": "timeFormat(time, '%b %e')", "as": "val"}
],
"mark": {
"type": "text",
"radius": 75,
"fontSize": 18,
"fontWeight": 400,
"font": "Arial"
},
"encoding": {
"theta": {"field": "pos"},
"text": {"field": "val"},
"fill": {
"condition": [{"test": "datum.pos == 1", "value": "#B3B3B3"}],
"value": "transparent"
}
}
},
{
"transform": [
{"calculate": "sequence(0,5, 1)", "as": "pos"},
{"flatten": ["pos"]},
{"calculate": "timeFormat(time, '%H:%M:%S')", "as": "val"}
],
"mark": {
"type": "text",
"radius": 75,
"fontSize": 18,
"fontWeight": 400,
"font": "Arial"
},
"encoding": {
"theta": {"field": "pos"},
"text": {"field": "val"},
"fill": {
"condition": [{"test": "datum.pos == 2", "value": "#B3B3B3"}],
"value": "transparent"
}
}
},
{
"transform": [
{"calculate": "sequence(1,61, 1)", "as": "minute"},
{"flatten": ["minute"]},
{
"sort": [{"field": "minute"}],
"window": [{"op": "sum", "field": "value", "as": "Cumulat"}],
"frame": [null, 0]
},
{
"calculate": "round(((datum.Cumulat / 60) * 360)-180,2)",
"as": "percentage"
}
],
"mark": {
"type": "point",
"angle": {"expr": "datum.percentage"},
"shape": {"expr": "_svg_marker"}
},
"encoding": {
"fill": {
"condition": [
{
"test": "toNumber(datum.minute) === minutes(time)",
"value": "#F79100"
},
{
"test": {
"field": "minute",
"oneOf": [0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 60]
},
"value": "#1C1C1E"
}
],
"value": "#B3B3B3"
},
"stroke": {
"condition": [
{
"test": "toNumber(datum.minute) === minutes(time)",
"value": "#F79100"
},
{
"test": {
"field": "minute",
"oneOf": [0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 60]
},
"value": "#1C1C1E"
}
],
"value": "#B3B3B3"
}
}
},
{
"transform": [
{"calculate": "sequence(1,13, 1)", "as": "hour"},
{"flatten": ["hour"]}
],
"mark": {
"type": "text",
"radius": 145,
"fontSize": 40,
"fontWeight": 600,
"font": "Arial"
},
"encoding": {
"theta": {"field": "hour", "type": "quantitative"},
"text": {"field": "hour"},
"color": {
"condition": {
"test": "datum.hour == hours(time) || datum.hour == hours(time)-12",
"value": "#F79100"
},
"value": "#1C1C1E"
}
}
},
{
"transform": [
{
"calculate": "(minutes(time)+seconds(time)/60) * 6",
"as": "min_degrees"
}
],
"layer": [
{
"mark": {
"type": "point",
"size": 5.1,
"shape": {"expr": "_svg_min"},
"angle": {"expr": "datum.min_degrees"}
},
"encoding": {
"fill": {"value": "#515157"},
"stroke": {"value": "#515157"},
"opacity": {"value": 1}
}
},
{
"mark": {
"type": "point",
"size": 5.1,
"shape": {"expr": "_svg_min_big"},
"angle": {"expr": "datum.min_degrees"}
},
"encoding": {
"fill": {"value": "#1C1C1E"},
"stroke": {"value": "#1C1C1E"},
"opacity": {"value": 1}
}
}
]
},
{
"transform": [
{
"calculate": "(hours(time)+minutes(time)/60)  * 30",
"as": "hr_degrees"
}
],
"layer": [
{
"mark": {
"type": "point",
"size": 5.1,
"shape": {"expr": "_svg_hr"},
"angle": {"expr": "datum.hr_degrees"}
},
"encoding": {
"fill": {"value": "#515157"},
"stroke": {"value": "#515157"},
"opacity": {"value": 1}
}
},
{
"mark": {
"type": "point",
"size": 5.1,
"shape": {"expr": "_svg_hr_big"},
"angle": {"expr": "datum.hr_degrees"}
},
"encoding": {
"fill": {"value": "#1C1C1E"},
"stroke": {"value": "#1C1C1E"},
"opacity": {"value": 1}
}
}
]
},
{
"transform": [
{
"calculate": "(seconds(time)+milliseconds(time)/1000) * 6",
"as": "sec_degrees"
}
],
"mark": {
"type": "point",
"size": 5.1,
"shape": {"expr": "_svg_sec"},
"angle": {"expr": "datum.sec_degrees"}
},
"encoding": {"fill": {"value": "#F79100"}, "stroke": {"value": "#F79100"}}
},
{
"mark": {"type": "circle", "size": 200},
"encoding": {"color": {"value": "#F79100"}, "opacity": {"value": 1}}
},
{
"mark": {"type": "circle", "size": 50},
"encoding": {"color": {"value": "#FFF"}, "opacity": {"value": 1}}
}
]
}
```

**Dark theme:**

[image]

```
{
"$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
"data": {"values": [{"value": 1}]},
"params": [
{
"name": "_svg_marker",
"value": "M -0.5 70 a 0.5 0.5 0 1 0 1 0 v -4 a 0.5 0.5 0 1 0 -1 0 z"
},
{
"name": "_svg_min",
"value": "M -2 0 a 2 2 0 1 0 4 0 v -130 a 2 2 0 1 0 -4 0 z"
},
{
"name": "_svg_min_big",
"value": "M -4 -25 a 4 4 0 1 0 8 0 v -120 a 4 4 0 1 0 -8 0 z"
},
{
"name": "_svg_hr",
"value": "M -2 0 a 2 2 0 1 0 4 0 v -90 a 2 2 0 1 0 -4 0 z"
},
{
"name": "_svg_hr_big",
"value": "M -4 -25 a 4 4 0 1 0 8 0 v -70 a 4 4 0 1 0 -8 0 z"
},
{"name": "_svg_sec", "value": "M 0 -170 l 0 190"},
{
"name": "time",
"on": [{"events": {"type": "timer", "throttle": 10}, "update": "now()"}]
}
],
"layer": [
{
"mark": {"type": "arc", "outerRadius": 200, "innerRadius": 0},
"encoding": {"fill": {"value": "#343436"}}
},
{
"mark": {"type": "circle", "size": 500},
"encoding": {"color": {"value": "#DDDCE0"}, "opacity": {"value": 1}}
},
{
"transform": [
{"calculate": "sequence(0,5, 1)", "as": "pos"},
{"flatten": ["pos"]},
{"calculate": "timeFormat(time, '%A')", "as": "val"}
],
"mark": {
"type": "text",
"radius": 75,
"fontSize": 28,
"fontWeight": 400,
"font": "Arial"
},
"encoding": {
"theta": {"field": "pos"},
"text": {"value": "VL"},
"fill": {
"condition": [{"test": "datum.pos == 4", "value": "#F79100"}],
"value": "transparent"
}
}
},
{
"transform": [
{"calculate": "sequence(0,5, 1)", "as": "pos"},
{"flatten": ["pos"]},
{"calculate": "timeFormat(time, '%A')", "as": "val"}
],
"mark": {
"type": "text",
"radius": 75,
"fontSize": 18,
"fontWeight": 400,
"font": "Arial"
},
"encoding": {
"theta": {"field": "pos"},
"text": {"field": "val"},
"fill": {
"condition": [{"test": "datum.pos == 3", "value": "#AEADB2"}],
"value": "transparent"
}
}
},
{
"transform": [
{"calculate": "sequence(0,5, 1)", "as": "pos"},
{"flatten": ["pos"]},
{"calculate": "timeFormat(time, '%b %e')", "as": "val"}
],
"mark": {
"type": "text",
"radius": 75,
"fontSize": 18,
"fontWeight": 400,
"font": "Arial"
},
"encoding": {
"theta": {"field": "pos"},
"text": {"field": "val"},
"fill": {
"condition": [{"test": "datum.pos == 1", "value": "#AEADB2"}],
"value": "transparent"
}
}
},
{
"transform": [
{"calculate": "sequence(0,5, 1)", "as": "pos"},
{"flatten": ["pos"]},
{"calculate": "timeFormat(time, '%H:%M:%S')", "as": "val"}
],
"mark": {
"type": "text",
"radius": 75,
"fontSize": 18,
"fontWeight": 400,
"font": "Arial"
},
"encoding": {
"theta": {"field": "pos"},
"text": {"field": "val"},
"fill": {
"condition": [{"test": "datum.pos == 2", "value": "#AEADB2"}],
"value": "transparent"
}
}
},
{
"transform": [
{"calculate": "sequence(1,61, 1)", "as": "minute"},
{"flatten": ["minute"]},
{
"sort": [{"field": "minute"}],
"window": [{"op": "sum", "field": "value", "as": "Cumulat"}],
"frame": [null, 0]
},
{
"calculate": "round(((datum.Cumulat / 60) * 360)-180,2)",
"as": "percentage"
}
],
"mark": {
"type": "point",
"angle": {"expr": "datum.percentage"},
"shape": {"expr": "_svg_marker"}
},
"encoding": {
"fill": {
"condition": [
{
"test": "toNumber(datum.minute) === minutes(time)",
"value": "#F79100"
},
{
"test": {
"field": "minute",
"oneOf": [0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 60]
},
"value": "#F5F4F9"
}
],
"value": "#5C5C5C"
},
"stroke": {
"condition": [
{
"test": "toNumber(datum.minute) === minutes(time)",
"value": "#F79100"
},
{
"test": {
"field": "minute",
"oneOf": [0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 60]
},
"value": "#F5F4F9"
}
],
"value": "#5C5C5C"
}
}
},
{
"transform": [
{"calculate": "sequence(1,13, 1)", "as": "hour"},
{"flatten": ["hour"]}
],
"mark": {
"type": "text",
"radius": 145,
"fontSize": 40,
"fontWeight": 600,
"font": "Arial"
},
"encoding": {
"theta": {"field": "hour", "type": "quantitative"},
"text": {"field": "hour"},
"color": {
"condition": {
"test": "datum.hour == hours(time) || datum.hour == hours(time)-12",
"value": "#F79100"
},
"value": "#F5F4F9"
}
}
},
{
"transform": [
{
"calculate": "(minutes(time)+seconds(time)/60) * 6",
"as": "min_degrees"
}
],
"layer": [
{
"mark": {
"type": "point",
"size": 5.1,
"shape": {"expr": "_svg_min"},
"angle": {"expr": "datum.min_degrees"}
},
"encoding": {
"fill": {"value": "#DDDCE0"},
"stroke": {"value": "#DDDCE0"},
"opacity": {"value": 1}
}
},
{
"mark": {
"type": "point",
"size": 5.1,
"shape": {"expr": "_svg_min_big"},
"angle": {"expr": "datum.min_degrees"}
},
"encoding": {
"fill": {"value": "#F5F4F9"},
"stroke": {"value": "#F5F4F9"},
"opacity": {"value": 1}
}
}
]
},
{
"transform": [
{
"calculate": "(hours(time)+minutes(time)/60)  * 30",
"as": "hr_degrees"
}
],
"layer": [
{
"mark": {
"type": "point",
"size": 5.1,
"shape": {"expr": "_svg_hr"},
"angle": {"expr": "datum.hr_degrees"}
},
"encoding": {
"fill": {"value": "#DDDCE0"},
"stroke": {"value": "#DDDCE0"},
"opacity": {"value": 1}
}
},
{
"mark": {
"type": "point",
"size": 5.1,
"shape": {"expr": "_svg_hr_big"},
"angle": {"expr": "datum.hr_degrees"}
},
"encoding": {
"fill": {"value": "#F5F4F9"},
"stroke": {"value": "#F5F4F9"},
"opacity": {"value": 1}
}
}
]
},
{
"transform": [
{
"calculate": "(seconds(time)+milliseconds(time)/1000) * 6",
"as": "sec_degrees"
}
],
"mark": {
"type": "point",
"size": 5.1,
"shape": {"expr": "_svg_sec"},
"angle": {"expr": "datum.sec_degrees"}
},
"encoding": {"fill": {"value": "#F79100"}, "stroke": {"value": "#F79100"}}
},
{
"mark": {"type": "circle", "size": 200},
"encoding": {"color": {"value": "#F79100"}, "opacity": {"value": 1}}
},
{
"mark": {"type": "circle", "size": 50},
"encoding": {"color": {"value": "#FFF"}, "opacity": {"value": 1}}
}
]
}
```

Happy charting!

Adam